# choose specifec 'span' tag if duplicatied

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python-3.5

there is two span tags in my page 
and i tried that method

```
web.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="_54nh"]').click()
```

it goes to wrong span not what i want 
so i need to select with 'Delete' text that is difference from the another tag 
there is html source

```
▼<span>
  <span class="_54nh">
</span>
```

and that what i need to select

```
  ▼<span>
    <span class="_54nh">Delete</span>
  </span>
```

the difference is the  'Delete' word

Comment: You need to assign  `id` to your span tag to differentiate and then try !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refine the `xpath` by adding the intended text in your search criteria as follows:

```
web.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='_54nh'][text()='Delete']").click()
```

Comment: @Fathy Glad to be able to help you.